# Start video read from a particular frame

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hsv

I have obtained the frame_count of a saved video.

```
self.frame_count = self.capture.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) - 1
```

Now, I want to start a frame read from a particular frame_count. How do I do this?

**Reason**: I need to track an object and I have found the location of the object I want to track using HSV image segmentation. Now to track it, I intend to start the video from that particular frame and set the track window to the objects' coordinates.

**Want**: It should not be redundant and computationally intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
f = # put here the frame from which you want to start
self.capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, f)
while f < self.frame_count:
    retval, image = self.capture.read()
    f += 1
```

Comment: I had something like that in mind but that is too computation intensive. Since it will need to read the "unwanted" frames until it gets to the right one. I want an optimal way of doing it.

Comment: Set the frame to be captured next with `capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame)` before you start reading with `read()`

Comment: @tilaprimera I've modified the answer according to my previous comment

Comment: Edited your answer. Could you please check that and notify me?

Comment: @tilaprimera Just saw your edit pop up in the review queue—it was rejected for being too big a change to the original answer, so I'll post the changes here. Two lines were changed: `self.capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, f)` and `while f < total_frames:`.

Comment: @JordanGray Wonder why that happened. Thanks for posting it here.

Comment: @JordanGray I've modified my answer with your first suggestion. I left `self.frame_count` unchanged because this is where the question stores the value. `total_frames` is not (visible) in the question.

Comment: @tilaprimera When edits appear in the review queue, we can't see the comments, so we didn't know that you and **wolfrevo** were collaborating to improve the answer. It's a small edit, but because it changed the meaning of the post it gets classed as a "radical change". :) Best way to get around that is to use a service like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [Gists](https://gist.github.com/) to share code samples!

Comment: That makes sense. (I should mention that it was @tilaprimera's suggestion, so good job to them!)

Comment: Thanks everyone for such quick response. I am working on my code and once it works, I will post here.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code to accomplish your task. 
The Opencv version you are using is old. Use Opencv2. 
Link : 
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

cam = cv2.VideoCapture('full_path/bird.avi')
i = 1 
initialize_first_frame = cam.read()[1]
start_from_frame = 5
dir =  './testImages/'
os.makedirs(dir)
while True:
    if(i>=start_from_frame):
      cv2.imshow('Frame Conversion',cam.read()[1])
      cv2.imwrite(dir + "/image-"+str(i).zfill(5)+".png",cam.read()[1])
    i = i + 1    
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
       cv2.destroyWindow('Frame Conversion')
       break
print "End"
```

I hope this is the code you want.

Comment: I do use the cv2 interface. Thank you again for the elaborate code. I have lots of edits to do on my code to figure out if it is actually working. So more updates later.

Comment: I too creating code to track an object using python opencv2. I have some doubts in that. May I know your email id to ask its related questions pls ... ?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python I suppose you could always ask here or post questions here. I am a noob myself. : )

Answer (score 0):

For any version 3 and 4 of OpenCV Python, follow this -

```
import cv2
# suppose you want to start reading from frame no 500
frame_set_no = 500 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("full_path/cow.mp4")
 
# capture is set to the desired frame
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_set_no)

while True:
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```